# Automate answer to jar through shell

Tags: java, shell

I have a jar file that ask inputs from a user for basic information:
Owner:
License:
Number of users:
This would create a registry file after once it gets these inputs above

Since the information are standard we wanted to automate it:

We were calling the jar file inside a shell

```
#call jar file
java -jar info.jar<<EOF
Owner1
xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx
999
EOF
```

The problem I'm having is that after it enter Owner1, it would quit out from shell and does not enter the other details.Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: running this on Rhel 5u5 Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Windows, you might want to consider [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). In your case, it would probably look like

```
Run("cmd.exe")
WinWaitActive("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
Send("java -jar info.jar{ENTER}")
Sleep(1000)
Send("Owner1{ENTER}")
Send("xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx{ENTER}")
Send("999{ENTER}")
```